# PHP, классы, проверка уникальности экземпляра

Tags: ооп, php

Доброго времени суток.

Возникла у меня хитрая задача. Мы знаем, что в PHP можно создать неопределенное кол-во экземпляров одного и того же класса. Но вот столкнулся я с задачей - необходимо проверять некоторые экземпляры на уникальность (для экономии времени).

Простой пример:

Сижу я и кодю. Вдруг мне понадобилось Создать экземпляр класса, создаю. Например:

```
$conn = new Connector($params);
```

Где-то в соседней комнате сидит еще один Валера и ему тоже понадобился экземпляр этого же класса. Он его создает. Разумеется, получается, 2 экземпляра.

Почему встал вопрос. Дело том, что назначение этого класса в соединении со сторонним сервером и обработка приходящих от него параметров. Получается так, что по итогу скрипт жрет в 2 раза больше трафика, ресурсов => падает скорость.

Когда это всплывет - может быть таких Валер (как мы с Валерой #1), которым нужен будет этот класс много-много :)

Так вот. Фишка в чем. У меня в голове всплыла такая мысля как проверка класса на уникальность. (сравнить нужно по передаваемым параметрам в класс, и по его имени).

Может кто сталкивался ? Подскажите, пожалуйста. В какую сторону лучше копать ?:))

У меня была мысля - сделать промежуточный класс - объект `ObjectInstances()`, который бы в себе содержал 2 функции:

1. регистрация ссылок на объект `get_instance("string")`
2. удаление если ссылок больше нет. `remove_instance()`

и счетчик кол-ва ссылок.

Т.е. смысл в том, чтобы эти классы создавать в этом промежуточном, а передавать их разработчику через функцию, `get_instance()` получал ссылку на созданный в `ObjectInstances()` объект.

Исходя из параметров для сравнения (я их выше привел), можно генерить `guid` этого класса и при вызове `get_instance()` проверять на схожесть гуидов. Если такой есть - передаем ссылку на готовый экземпляр, если нет, создаем и передаем.

---

В общем, наверное, я Вас запутал.
Так, ладно, теперь слушаю Ваши мнения :) Как Вы считаете, такая конструкция подойдет ?

Если не подойдет (есть что-то стандартное), пожалуйста, ткните меня носом в то, как избежать создания одинаковых экземпляров классов :)

Спасибо заранее :)

========================= ЗЫ - **DEX**

Вы не поняли сути.

Вы задали вопрос "Если каждый экземпляр класса обрабатывает одни и те же данные от сервера то зачем несколько экземпляров вообще"

Именно это и нужно предусмотреть :))) Если бы я разрабатывал проект водиночку - без вопросов. Я бы даже не думал об этом.... НО!... работать над ним будет большое кол-во народу, которые, в свою очередь, не будут знать о том создавал ли кто-то этот объект ранее...или не создавал :)
А принцип ссылок прост -

$conn = new Connector($params);
$link = $conn;

Вот и будет этот $link ссылкой на $conn. Дальнейшее изменение в $link потянет изменение и в экземпляре $conn :) Так в Сях делаю. Думал, что в PHP есть что-то стандартизированное для таких нужд.

============================== **Немного об архитектуре** =========================

ссылка на документацию: [MHC - docs](http://docs.tracking.by/classsmc.html)

Смотрим что получается.

```
$test = new WialonConnection();
if(!$test->connect())
    echo $test->get_last_error();
$test = smc::cast($test, "User");
print_r($test->test123 . " " . get_class($test));
```

Выхлоп:  **123123123 User**

Если сделаем так: 
**$test = new User();
print_r($test->test123 . " " . get_class($test));**

Выхлоп: **User**

Т.е. Мои классы можно будет приводить к необходимому типу. 
Заметьте, есть промежуточный объект: **smc_object**
Собственно, в который я и хочу сохранять линки на уже созданные экземпляры.

Вот так.

Comment: Если каждый экземпляр класса обрабатывает одни и те же данные от сервера то зачем несколько экземпляров вообще (один собирает -> сохраняет -> остальные разгребают)? Если разные - то вы теряете только на дополнительном соединении, при этом обмен данными что в первом, что во втором случае будет одинаков (вам в любом случае запрос/ответ делать).

Каким образом вы хотите реализовать обмен ссылками на экземпляры объектов, т.е. каким образом из двух различных точек входа (как я понял из вашего пояснения) вы хотите получить доступ к `ObjectInstances`?

Может я что-то не так понял?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю вам подойдет такой паттерн как **Singleton**.

почитать и посмотреть примеры можно [тут](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php#singleton)

Comment: О,  таки да. Структура похожая  на мою задумку :) Спасибо большое )

Comment: Не забывайте принимать ответы ;)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы снизить нагрузку, можно использовать статические методы (привязаны к классу, а не к его экземплярам). А вместо создания экземпляра использовать ссылку на класс.